# sh script does not work from crontab

Tags: mysql, sql, debian, sh

I have a Debian server and

I need a sh script which calls sql-script

in order to get some data from MySQL table

So I connect via ssh as root to my server and created all the files

Please note that I used full path to all the files in the script

in order to avoid misinterpretations.

**/root/bin/mgbc.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

(echo "SET @cid=570; SET @cid2='service@';" ; cat /root/bin/mgbc.sql) |/full-path-to/mysql -uusername -pservetword  > /root/bin/result_mgbc.txt
```

**/root/bin/mgbc.sql**

```
SELECT  table1.id, table1.a_id, table2.email
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.a_id=table2.id
AND table1.campaign_id = @cid
AND table2.email LIKE CONCAT('%', @cid2 ,'%')
;
```

let`s run it

```
*/root/bin/mgbc.sh*
```

and in the `*/root/bin/result_mgbc.txt*`
I see

`*table1.id`, `table1.a_id`, `table2.email`*

and lot of lines

Then I decided to put it as a crontab task

so I entered

```
crontab -e
```

and added a line

```
35 10 1 * * /root/bin/mgbc.sh
```

I see from a crontab log file that the script is started, 
but in the `*/root/bin/result_mgbc.txt*`
I see the field list only

```
table1.id, table1.a_id, table2.email
```

and no data at all.

Looks like *@cid* and *@cid2* parameters are lost somewhere 
when the crontab runs the script.

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how to solve that?

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: I doubt that echoing command string actually does execute them. Investigate this.

Comment: Yes, looks like this. 

Since my idea was to exclude any parameters from the sh-script and then run it as 

/root/bin/mgbc.sh 570 'service@'

I think it is better to forget about it :-)

Comment: 70+ Q/A when searching here for `[linux] does not work from crontab`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add your SET statements to mgbc.sql and run it like this

`/full-path-to/mysql -uusername -pservetword < /root/bin/mgbc.sql > /root/bin/result_mgbc.txt`

or

`/full-path-to/mysql -uusername -pservetword -e "SET @cid=570; SET @cid2='service@';" -e  "$(cat /root/bin/mgbc.sql)" > /root/bin/result_mgbc.txt`

or you can build the sql file on the fly based on input params.

not sure if this would work

`/full-path-to/mysql -uusername -pservetword -e "SET @cid=570; SET @cid2='service@';" < /root/bin/mgbc.sql > /root/bin/result_mgbc.txt`

Comment: That will work, I tried it before, but I do need set in my sh,
in order to make it in future run like 
/root/bin/mgbc.sh parameter1 parameter2....

Got no clue why via crontab this does not fly.

Comment: Added more options, see if they work better for you.

Comment: Thank you, your example

   ` /full-path-to/mysql -uusername -pservetword -e "SET @cid=570; SET @cid2='service@';" -e  "$(cat /root/bin/mgbc.sql)" > /root/bin/result_mgbc.txt `

works fine from command line,

but not from crontab.

Comment: That's weird. What's the problem on crontab. Paste the error if any.

Comment: I wish I could see any error. But there are no errors. I wonder if you have a chance to try the same on your side :-). There is one thing I`m sure - SET parameters are not come to the mysql in my case. Hence I would need to make couple of sql-scrits with the SETs include and then use it in crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
The bottle neck is "%"

In order to make it all work properly I needed to do this:

**/root/bin/mgbc.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

(/bin/echo "SET @cid=570; SET @cid2='something@';" ; cat /root/bin/mgbc.sql) | /usr/bin/mysql -uusername -pservetword  > /root/bin/result_mgbc.txt
```

The SQL-script

```
SET @percent := '%' ;

SELECT  table1.id, table1.a_id, table2.email
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.a_id=table2.id
AND table1.campaign_id = @cid
AND table2.email LIKE CONCAT(@percent, @cid2 , @percent)
;
```

The **SET @percent := '%'** has fixed the isue,

since the *crontab* could not work with the percentage sign.

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: This doesn't answer your Q. But it does make clear what you have tried and should be moved to the body of your main Q above, while this (non-)answer should be removed. Welcome to StackOverflow, and Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.